# Problem synchronizing DOM manipulation with style changes in carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery

I built a basic picture carousel a while back, and I'm finally getting around to transferring it from MooTools over to jQuery so I can drop MooTools. I've got the script completely functional, but for whatever reason when the carousel slides in one direction, you can see a "pop" where it resets itself.

I've tried playing around with the order it handles everything, but no matter what it seems to always desync for just a fraction of a section.

Here's a copy of my code: https://jsfiddle.net/Chaosxmk/pf6dzchm/
The offending section of code is this:

```
styles['position'] = 'absolute';
styles[self.params.axis] = -32768;
$(self.list[0]).css(styles).hide();

$(self.list[0]).appendTo(self.carousel);

$(self.list[conf.mi]).css(self.params.axis, (100-conf.pr)+'%');

styles = {};
styles['position'] = 'relative';
styles[self.params.axis] = 'auto';
$(self.list[conf.mi]).css(styles);
```

Comment: What leads you to believe that's the offending section of code?

Comment: It's the block of code that resets the styles back to "default" values and edits the DOM elements. It's the only section I can think of as being the core issue, although I suppose it's entirely possible that the block that sets up and does the animation could have an error that cascades down to the reset here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is that `$.fadeOut()` sets `display:none` on the element, which causes some strange rendering issues in your `setTimeout()` callback. Works better if you use `$.fadeTo()` instead:

```
if (self.params.direction) {
    // Go forward
    self.carousel.css(self.params.axis, '-'+conf.pr+'%');
    $(self.list[0]).fadeTo(400, 0);
    $(self.list[conf.mi]).css(self.params.axis, '100%').fadeTo(400, 1);
} else {
    // Go backward
    self.carousel.css(self.params.axis, conf.pr+'%');
    $(self.list[conf.mi-1]).fadeTo(400, 0);
    self.list.last().css(self.params.axis, '-'+conf.pr+'%').fadeTo(400, 1);
}
```

For simplicity I used a 400ms duration, but you can set this to whatever you need.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c1f0az9n/)